# Display SharePoint 2007 User Profile Images

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Custom list in SharePoint 2007 which has information about users, it has person or Group field which displays (Name with Picture).

I need to view this information in a separate page with different style.
I have used SPD and added a Data View, but i cant get the pictures in the view.
How can i display pictures in the Data view?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in this article:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/04/sharepoint-displaying-pictures-and.html

For more information, please refer to:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/712bd76b-ca7f-4590-9dac-314a4abdc368/

Hope this helps.